# Загрузка фотографий из галереи в imageview

Tags: java, android, imageview

В моем приложении есть возможность добавить imageview на layout (из кода, соответственно). А потом загрузка из галереи:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    switch(requestCode) {
        case GALLERY_REQUEST:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                imageViews[ID].setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
    }
}
```

Все imageview, которые я добавляю, я загружаю в массив imageviews. Это нужно для того, чтобы пользователь мог создавать контекстное меню для определенного view элемента (их может бы столько, сколько создал пользователь).

Когда я добавил 3 картинки в 3 imageView приложение начинает тормозить и на android monitor сильно показывается нагрузка на процессор. И чем больше фоток тем сильнее тормозит.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для загрузки изображения [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). У вас сейчас без каких-либо оптимизаций `bitmap` кладется в `imageview`. Это может привести и к переполнению памяти. Glide поможет вам этого избежать.